# Array push does not do his job

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

Why does `container.push(random[0])` not work?

I can't find a solution to the problem... I need to put the HTML Object into the container array, and well it does not go there.

```js
let container = new Array();
let x = document.querySelectorAll('.trigger');

function getFlag() {
  let random = [x[Math.floor(Math.random() * x.length)]];

  if (!container.includes(random[0])) {
    random[0].classList.remove('trigger');

    console.log('random n: ' + random[0]);
    container.push(random[0]);
  }
}

console.log('x length: ' + x.length)
console.log('array length: ' + container.length)
```

```css
.trigger {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body onload="getFlag()">
  <section class="trigger">
    <p>1</p>
  </section>
  <section class="trigger">
    <p>2</p>
  </section>
  <section class="trigger">
    <p>3</p>
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: Why do you think `push` does not work? A `<section>` element _is_ in the array at the end. Don’t concatenate everything to a string; use `console.log("random n:", random[0])` to test your values. Use `console.log(container.slice());` to see the current state of your array; I don’t see you actually confirming your expected result anywhere. What’s the point of `random` being an array and getting `random[0]` all the time instead of `random`?

Comment: If you are referring to the fact that `console.log('array length: ' + container.length)` shows `0` instead of `1`, the reason is that the `console.log()` is executed before `getFlag()` can actually push the element into `container`. If you move that line inside the `getFlag()` function body you'll see it correctly displays `1`.

Comment: Well i would like to use `random` but if i give  `random.classList.remove('trigger')` to classList it gives me back an error.

Comment: That is because you set `random` to be an array; if you replace `let random = [x[Math.floor(Math.random() * x.length)]];` with `let random = x[Math.floor(Math.random() * x.length)];` (without the out-most square brackets) you can refer to the element using just `random` instead of `random[0]`

Comment: Oh wow i didn't know that it could be possible thanks! now i've fixed my code. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

try this maybe:

```js
let container = [];
let x = document.querySelectorAll('.trigger');

function getFlag() {
  console.log("pushed");
  
   /*When you click on the button, if "pushed" is not logged, here's an error*/
  
  let random = [x[Math.floor(Math.random() * x.length)]];

  if (!container.includes(random[0])) {
    random[0].classList.remove('trigger');

    console.log('random n: ' + random[0]);
    container.push(random[0]);
    
    console.log('x length: ' + x.length)
    console.log('array length: ' + container.length)
  }
}
```

if you log the length of the array after the function pushed the random to the array, maybe you will get the result